# How to achieve thin font in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I noticed many questions about changing font in ActionBar, but unfortunately any of them satisfied me. 
I want to achieve thin font like in Inbox app.

[image: Inbox]

I tried to change style :

```
<style name="AppThemeWithActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppThemeWithActionBar.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeWithActionBar.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppThemeWithActionBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppThemeWithActionBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeWithActionBar.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

What I get is grey action bar without title.

Comment: You want to add another font or you just want to reduce the size of the text?

Comment: I want to get the same look like in Inbox, whatever it is, smaller text or another font.

Comment: Are you using Toolbar or ActionBar?

Comment: ActionBar, as u can notice in styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the title at runtime with a `Spannable`. You should be able to do something like:

```
SpannableString title = new SpannableString("Your Title");

// Add a span for the sans-serif-light font
title.setSpan(
        new TypefaceSpan("sans-serif-light"), 
        0, 
        title.length(), 
        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

// Add a span for the smaller font size
title.setSpan(
        new AbsoluteSizeSpan(12, true /* dip */),
        0,
        title.length(),
        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

actionBar.setTitle(title);
```

Comment: Perfect, how can I set smaller text?

Comment: Could do the same, but also call `setSpan()` with an `AbsoluteSizeSpan`.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want a small title I did this on one of my samples to get a small title :

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<small>TITLEGOESHERE</small>"));
```

Other example would be put on your styles of your `ActionBar`

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/CustomSizeActionBar</item>
```

Where `CustomSizeActionBar` it's :

```
<style name="CustomSizeActionBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Hope it what you want.

Comment: I don't know why, but when I am using styles like in question I can't see title.

Comment: You don't see nothing?

Comment: I see only buttons on actionbar

Comment: But if you start from 0, without styles what you get? Test it on a sample project and let me know if it's what you want.

Comment: If I'm not using style for action bar everything is ok, but if I use code as in question, I can't see title

Comment: Then don't do that, and implement the code that I've put on my answer .

Comment: But with your code I can't see this too, could you write whole styles.xml ? Maybe I 'm doing something wrong

Comment: With the other asnwer you can see text?

Comment: Yes, without styles I can see title.

Comment: Then just add the first code I gave to you (java code) and implement it on your Activity you want to show the small text

Comment: With html works, but another question works better. Thank you !